# svg-edit - set background dynamically

Tags: svg-edit

I'm looking at using svg-edit to annotate images in a browser.  The image is uploaded on the same page the svg-edit is embedded in and needs to be set dynamically on upload as the background for svg-edit.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the method of the object i.e svgCanvas.setBackground();

For this you can create an extension e.g : ext-backchange.js

this file look likes this:

```
svgEditor.addExtension("changeback", function() {


svgCanvas.setBackground('','abc.png');

return {};
});
```

Then include this extension in svg-edit.js as in the last line :

```
 svgEditor.setConfig(
{

extensions: ['ext-backchange.js']

 })
```

Comment: i have created file 'ext-backchange.js' and included extension as well. where should I put svgCanvas.setBackground(); now?

Comment: Inside ext-backchange.js as mentioned in the answer under callback function of changeback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setImageBackground(imageBackground) function

```
setImageBackground("image.png");
```

and add this function setImageBackground in svgcanvas.js  This image appear on the canvas and can be rotated.

```
this.setImageBackground= function(val) {

var elem = addSvgElementFromJson({
    "element": "image",
    "attr": {
        "x": ( svgcontent.getAttribute('x') - bgimg_with ) / 2,
        "y": ( svgcontent.getAttribute('y') - bgimg_height ) / 2,
        "width": bgimg_with,
        "height": bgimg_height,
        "id": 'ImgBckgd',
        "opacity": 1,
        "style": "pointer-events:inherit",
    }
});

setHref(elem, last_good_img_url);
preventClickDefault(elem);      
if(!elem) return;   
var attrs = $(elem).attr(['width', 'height']);
var setsize = (!attrs.width || !attrs.height);
var cur_href = getHref(elem);   
// Do nothing if no URL change or size change
if(cur_href !== val) {
    setsize = true;
} else if(!setsize) return;
var batchCmd = new BatchCommand("Change Image URL");
setHref(elem, val);
batchCmd.addSubCommand(new ChangeElementCommand(elem, {
    "#href": cur_href
}));
if(setsize) {
    $(new Image()).load(function() {
        var changes = $(elem).attr(['width', 'height']);        
        $(elem).attr({
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        });         
        selectorManager.requestSelector(elem).resize();         
        batchCmd.addSubCommand(new ChangeElementCommand(elem, changes));
        addCommandToHistory(batchCmd);
        call("changed", [elem]);
    }).attr('src',val);
} else {
    addCommandToHistory(batchCmd);
}
};
```